# File not found error while upload video files on youtube c#

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Try so many alternatives but stuck at `filenotfound` error. I need whole path in textbox and upload video on Youtube.

```
public void UploadFileonYouTube()
{
    string filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename);
            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
            Video newVideo = new Video();
            newVideo.Title = "Demo";
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Animals", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
            newVideo.Description = "You tube Api Integration Demo.";
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(fullpath, "video/x-ms-wmv");
            request.Upload(newVideo);
    //@"C:\head_rush4.wmv"
}
```

Design : `Fileupload` control for uploading file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Upload on YouTube" OnClick="Button2_Click1"  />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for your form.

```
string fullpath = FileUpload1.FileName;
```

the above code gives you just the file name, NOT file path.
[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: See in comment code i used server.mappath its is also not working in for uploading video.

Comment: The [MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server. It is using for find the path on server e.g `Server.MapPath(~/uploads/videos/)`